# OpenSessionInViewInterceptor in a non web application

Tags: spring, hibernate, open-session-in-view

I have to use OpenSessionInViewInterceptor in a non-web application. I have configured OSV Interceptor as follows,

```
<bean id="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
  <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory"/></property>   
</bean>
```

I'm getting a Lazy load exception. Any pointers to where I'm going wrong? Is the configuration correct?

Or does a non-web app require OpenSessionInViewFilter instead of interceptor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first line Java Doc of `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor`

> Spring web request interceptor that binds a Hibernate Session to the thread for the entire processing of the request.

So if you do not have a Web Request because you do not have a web application, then this Interceptor does not helps you.

The `OpenSessionInViewFilter` is for only Web Applications too.

So you will need to start your Session/Transaction "By Hand", for example with `@Transactional`.